# Facebook JSON page feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to pull the timeline feed from a Facebook page (not wall) I have the SDK etc. what is the correct code and what permissions do I need as this doesn't work?

```
include('src/facebook.php');
$fb_config = array(
        'appId'  => 'XXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXX'
);
$facebook = new Facebook($fb_config);
$feed = $facebook->api("/{PageID/feed");
print_r($feed);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explained on the Graph API [Page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed) documentation. You need to have an access token for the current user and use it when requesting the `/feed` connection for a Page. This is now the case for all Pages.